Project files not generating after uninstalling VS2022
I recently installed rider to test it with unreal engine to see if its a better pick than vs2022 and i haven't looked back since then. so i decided to delete vs2022 yesterday as i no longer have any use for it. i deleted it using Bulk Crap uninstaller so it doesn't leave any residual files and today i opened up my project and it refuses to compile and says
Generating VisualStudio project files
Discovering nodules, targets and source code for project...
No Visual C++ installation was found. Please download and install Visual Studio 2022 or 2019 with C++
cmponents.
Visual Studio 2022 x64 must be installed in order to build this target.

is there anyway to fix the issue without reinstalling vs2022
i deleted the binary, intermediate and saved folders to generate visual studio project files but it fails

The problem is needing the msvc compiler not the IDE. You can install the msvc build tools independently of the IDE.

To build an Unreal Engine project, you don't need Visual Studio itself, but you do need the correct compiler toolset, which in the case of Windows, is the MSVC compiler and associated tools, called "Build tools for Visual Studio".
Unreal has no official guide for setting up Rider, but the process for that is very similar to any other non-VS IDE, for example Visual Studio Code. So it's possible to follow the official guide for setting VSC, and skip the actual VSC related section, going instead directly to the section "Installing the compiler toolset".
Depedning on your engine version, you might need a different version of the Build Tools (they correspond to the Visual Studio version recommended by the Unreal docs -- see "version compatbility" section here).
When the correct Build Tools are installed, you should be able to generate .sln solutions, and build UE.
Note: Rider also can directly open a .uproject file, so with the Build Tools installed, you don't have to generate a VS solution, and can directly open the project file with Rider.
